# Tensor products, duals and the space C(K)

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products, dual-spaces

Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $E$ a Banach space, then $C(K)\otimes E$ can be identified with $C(K,E)$ using the injective tensor norm. 
Now I want to show that:

1. $(C(K))^{∗∗}\otimes E \subset C(K,E)^{∗∗}$

and 2. $(C(K))\otimes E^{∗∗} \subset C(K,E)^{∗∗}$

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.